# How to set the varchar encode when create a foreign table in tera data?

Tags: teradata

I have a sql command below, it can get NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA and return data column type.

```
SELECT ParquetColumnName,TDColumnType,ParquetColumnLogicalType
FROM READ_NOS_FM (
USING
STOREDAS('PARQUET')
FULLSCAN('TRUE')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA')
LOCATION('/s3/bXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/PARQUETDATA/)
) AS D;
```

result:

```
ParquetColumnName    TDColumnType    ParquetColumnLogicalType
------------------------------------------------------------------------
GageHeight2            FLOAT         NONE
Flow                   FLOAT         NONE
site_no                BIGINT        NONE
datetime               VARCHAR       UTF8
Precipitation          FLOAT         NONE
GageHeight             FLOAT         NONE
```

the question is when I create foreign table charset only can chose unicode (see below code block),

**utf8 and utf16 both chose unicode is correct? seems only this choice.**

**datetime VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC**

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE riverflow_parquet
, EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER TRUSTED DefAuth
(
  Location VARCHAR(2048) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC
  , GageHeight2 FLOAT  
  , Flow FLOAT 
  , site_no BIGINT
  , datetime VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC
  , Precipitation FLOAT 
  , GageHeight FLOAT 
)
USING (
    LOCATION('/s3/biXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/PARQUETDATA/')
    STOREDAS ('PARQUET')
) NO PRIMARY INDEX
```

Comment: Parquet strings are logical data type UTF8 and the database automatically converts to "server Unicode". Not sure about the context where you are asking about UTF16.

Comment: you are right.  NO support UTF16 .    https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md      copy  your answer to below answer field , I'll  chose your answer as  the correct answer.